# After a Git merge with no conflicts, a lot of files I didn't touch become both changes not staged for commit and changes staged for commit

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-stage

This question is very similar to [this question on merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189867/after-a-git-merge-conflict-a-lot-of-files-i-didnt-touch-become-changes-to-be-c) but with one key difference: the absence of a merge conflict.

So I'm working in a feature branch, commit some changes, and run `git merge master`. My goal is to update my feature branch with the latest master before I create a PR to merge the branch back into master (that is our chosen workflow, the idea is to resolve issues on feature branches first). I get zero merge conflicts and the merge seems to complete. When I run `git log` it appears that my feature branch now has the latest commits from master. However, when I run `git status` a bunch of files that I did not touch (but which appear to have been updated in master) suddenly enter my list of "Changes to committed", and a smattering of them appear as "Changes not staged for commit" and "Untracked files". It is not 1-to-1, in my latest example I had 45 files staged, but only 33 that were unstaged+modified or untracked. I am not committing these files as it does appear the feature branch already has the latest commits from master.

I have to date been dealing with this issue just by running `git stash` (and clearing my stash periodically). Sometimes I run `get reset HEAD` to clean it up too. This seems ok since I have the latest commits from master. However, I am not sure if these are desirable actions or the right thing to do. Am I missing a crucial piece of the git merge workflow by ignoring these staged files? What is going on here? What is the name of this behavior? I can't find a reference to this in any of the guides I've read.

One final note that might help. I am on a Mac, but this is a .net + React project, so many devs are on windows. Could this be an issue of autocrlf or other line ending variations between the platforms?

Comment: Use `git pull --rebase origin master` instead. Back merges is not good idea.

Comment: CRLF line ending issues are possible. To find out if this is the case, check for `.gitattributes` files with EOL directives, and check your own `core.autocrlf` setting.

Comment: The question is perfectly stated. Your workaround (stashing and then ignoring) is essentially the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50064776/264097) to essentially the same question. But none of the answers explain _why_ it happens. Have you found this out since four years ago?